# Extract Pingdom API data using GAS to google spreadsheet

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have extracted API data from Pingdom using GAS but, the only data that I was able to extract was..

```
TestID   |  TestName |  ResponseTime | Status
1299405     Google         243          up
1299434     Yahoo          342          up
1299499     Bling          299          up
```

by using this script..

```
function pingdom() {

var headers = 
{  
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "App-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Account-Email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
 var options = 
{ 
    "headers" : headers, 
    "method" : "get"
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/checks", options); 
var response_json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");


var rows = [], data; 

for (i = 0; i < response_json.checks["length"]; i++) { 
    data = response_json.checks[i]; 
    rows.push([data.id, data.name, data.lastresponsetime, data.status]); 
}

//Set column headings 
var colHeaders = [[ "Test ID", "Test Name", "Response Time", "Status"]]; 
dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 4); 
dataRange.setValues(colHeaders) ;

//Display data 
dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 4); 
dataRange.setValues(rows);
}
```

Now I am trying to extract some more data like "average response time & uptime"  Unfortunately Pingdom API only allows me to extract the data of a single testID (TestID is to be given in the API URL  https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/summary.performance/1299405?includeuptime=true)

by using this google script...

```
function uptime() {
var headers = 
{  
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "App-Key": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Account-Email": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
 var options = 
{ 
    "headers" : headers, 
    "method" : "get"
}

 var rows = [] , sum = {};
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/summary.performance/1299405?includeuptime=true", options); 
 var response_json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 
 //var sum = response_json.summary.states;
 for (i = 0; i < response_json.summary.hours.length; i++) 
 {
   sum = response_json.summary.hours[i] ;
 rows.push([sum["avgresponse"],sum["uptime"]]);
 break;
 }
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
 dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 2); 

  //Set column headings 
var colHeaders = [[ "avg","uptime"]]; 
dataRange.setValues(colHeaders) ;

//Display data 
dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows.length, 2); 
dataRange.setValues(rows);


}
```

I tried picking up the TestID from sheet1 and creating a loop so that I get the "average response time & uptime" of all the testID's present in the sheet1.

```
data_id = response_json.checks[i]; 
     //for ( i = response_json.checks.id; i++){
        var response1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.pingdom.com/api/2.0/summary.performance/" + data_id.id, options);
```

But unfortunately,  I am not able to pull any data. It would be really helpful if somebody could help me to achieve this.

(Here is the Pingdom API document - https://www.pingdom.com/resources/api)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by creating an array of your checks and loop through them. My sheets use this ID a lot so what I did was create a sheet that had all my checks in it and then I can use it all over the place. So my checkID sheet looks like this:

```
CheckName                  | CheckID
someendpoint.com/api         456213
someotherendpoint.com/api    456213
```

...etc

Then you can make a function and grab those values from the sheet. Here is an example of how to get it from the sheet and put it into an array:

```
var datetimeArr = new Array(); 
var ids =  new Array();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('checkID');
var names = s2.getRange('a1:a').getValues();
var ids = s2.getRange('b1:b').getValues();
```